# wsignoutcleanup1.0 not clearing session of current user

Tags: single-sign-on, wif

I have Implemented SSO with Windows Identity Framework, After Log out i am sending wsignoutcleanup1.0 requests to all RP's also want to Clear the session, but getting Exception of Session state is not available,

Can any one help me,

Using following code in Global.asax

```
protected void WSFederationAuthenticationModule_SigningOut(object sender,     Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SigningOutEventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.CookieHandler.Delete();
    Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.DeleteSessionTokenCookie();
    Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.SignOut();
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this post on the MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/Geneva/thread/57187c9e-4527-4b8d-b20e-f5fbb883a396), which provides a detailed explanation of the problem and solution.  Basically, the Session State is not available in Global ASAX, but it can be made available to an HTTP Module.